# Python error os.walk IOError

Tags: python, file-io, filepath

I tried to track the file with server in the filename and i can print all the file in directory with server** but when I try to read the file it gives me error" saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "view_log_packetloss.sh", line 27, in <module>
    with open(filename,'rb') as files:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pcoip_server_2014_05_19_00000560.txt'
```

I have seen similar question being asked but I could not fix mine, some error were fixed using chdir to change the current directory to the file directory. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

```
#!usr/bin/env/ python
import sys, re, os

#fucntion to find the packetloss data in pcoip server files
def function_pcoip_packetloss(filename):
        lineContains = re.compile('.*Loss=.*')  #look for "Loss=" in the file
        for line in filename:
                if lineContains.match(line):    #check if line matches "Loss="
                        print 'The file has: '  #prints if "Loss=" is found
                        print line
                        return 0;

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/users/home10/tshrestha/brb-view/logs/vdm-sdct-agent/pcoip-logs"):
        lineContainsServerFile = re.compile('.*server.*')
        for filename in files:
                if lineContainsServerFile.match(filename):
                        with open(filename,'rb') as files:
                                print 'filename'
                                function_pcoip_packetloss(filename);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the files are names of file objects in root directory.

> dirpath is a string, the path to the directory. dirnames is a list of the names of the subdirectories in dirpath (excluding '.' and '..'). filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in dirpath. Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).

try this

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/users/home10/tshrestha/brb-view/logs/vdm-sdct-agent/pcoip-logs"):
    lineContainsServerFile = re.compile('.*server.*')
    for filename in files:
            if lineContainsServerFile.match(filename):
                    filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    with open(filename,'rb') as files:
                            print 'filename:', filename
                            function_pcoip_packetloss(filename);
```

Comment: thank you for your help, it does not seems to work this way it just print 'filename' does not actually prints the filename.

Comment: but it opens correct filename **with open(filename,'rb') as files:**

Comment: OK, take the quotes off `'filename'` and then you will get the value of this variable. I'll edit the answer. But the important point is correct: you weren't including the directory path in the filenames you were trying to open.

Comment: thank you guys @holdenweb I can get the filename, I had it before too but while calling the function, it does not seem to work. Nothing happens, i was trying to parse in the file and print certain lines...I am trying to figure out why, any help is appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `os.walk()` function is a generator of 3-element tuples. Each tuple contains a directory as its first element. The second element is a list of subdirectories in that directory, and the third is a list of the files.

To generate the full path to each file it is necessary to concatenate the first entry (the directory path) and the filenames from the third entry (the files). The most straightforward and platform-agnostic way to do so uses `os.path.join()`.

Also note that it will be much more efficient to use

```
lineContainsServerFile = re.compile('server')
```

and `lineContainsServerFile.search()` rather than trying to match a wildcard string. Even in the first case the trailing `".*` is redundant, since what follows the `"server"` string is irrelevant.